# Rational singularity of Spec, Proj and Spec of localization of a standard graded $2$-dimensional ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, derived-functors, birational-geometry

If $X$ is a two dimensional Noetherian reduced excellent scheme, then we know by a [Theorem of Lipman](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971141?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) that $X$ has a desingularization, i.e., there exists a regular scheme $Y$ and a proper birational map $f: Y\to X$. A Noetherian reduced excellent scheme $X$ of dimension $2$ is said to have rational singularity if there exists a regular scheme $Y$ and a proper birational map $f: Y\to X$ such that $R^i f_*\mathcal O_Y=0,\forall i>0$.

Now let $k$ be a perfect field and $R=k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ be a standard graded ring of dimension $2$, where $I$ is a homogeneous radical ideal (hence $R$ is reduced) of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Let $\mathfrak m$ be the unique homogeneous maximal ideal of $R$. Consider the following statements:

(1) $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ has rational singularities

(2) $\operatorname{Proj}(R)$ has rational singularities

(3) $\operatorname{Spec}(R_{\mathfrak m})$ has rational singularities

(4) $\operatorname{Spec}(R_{P})$ has rational singularities for every maximal ideal $P$ of $R$

My question is: What is the relationship between these statements (1), (2), (3) and (4)? Is there any references where I can find implications between these statements?

(If needed, I'm willing to assume $R$ is a normal ring.)

Comment: One dimensional rings of your kind always have rational singularities, so 2 is always true. I believe other three are equivalent.